# BufWinLeave * mkview with unnamed file: Error 32

Tags: buffers, autocmd, error

Following this good [piece of advice](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/17c44eda91), I have added these lines to my `.vimrc`.

```
augroup AutoSaveFolds
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinLeave * mkview
  autocmd BufWinEnter * silent loadview
augroup END
```

It does work and my folds are saved. But I get this error now each time I open a unnamed buffer with;

```
:tabnew<cr>
```

or each time I navigate to help with

```
:tabhelp vim<cr>
```

with the following message:

```
Error detected while processing BufWinEnter Auto commands for "*":
E32: No file name
```

Why do I get this?
How to prevent it while still getting my folds automately saved?

Comment: I have no any idea why you needed to use tabs in vim, but i think that error arise when you create an unnamed buffer. Just try to open new tab like this ':tabnew ~/.vimrc' no any errors, if that file exactly exist.
Check the doc http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mkview

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Switching to `?*` as the regex will no longer match empty file names. I actually recommend you switch to the following, which is a corresponding block of `.vimrc` that has been tweaked to suppress many of the errors you are likely to encounter when following the referenced advice.

```
augroup AutoSaveGroup
  autocmd!
  " view files are about 500 bytes
  " bufleave but not bufwinleave captures closing 2nd tab
  " nested is needed by bufwrite* (if triggered via other autocmd)
  " BufHidden for compatibility with `set hidden`
  autocmd BufWinLeave,BufLeave,BufWritePost,BufHidden,QuitPre ?* nested silent! mkview!
  autocmd BufWinEnter ?* silent! loadview
augroup end
```

The `BufWritePost` event (+ `nested`) can be left out if you prefer, though you will experience no penalty for leaving it in.

Furthermore, I use

```
set viewoptions=folds,cursor
set sessionoptions=folds
```

Comment: Works perfectly, with nice additional tweaking options and explanations. Cheers :)

Comment: This appears to work perfectly with tabs. This might be a nice addition to the vim wikia site.

Comment: FWIW automatically restoring folds this way has caused some confusion for folks who are tweaking fold settings and not seeing any changes